# Monotouch animation acceleration

Tags: xamarin.ios, caanimation

Is it possible to create an animation with increasing speed? Something like accelerated animation.

I have some code but cannot find a way how to implement it. Googling also not helpful.

```
CABasicAnimation animation =  CABasicAnimation.FromKeyPath("opacity");
animation.To = NSNumber.FromFloat( 0.1f );
animation.Duration = 1.4f;
animation.Delegate = new ExponencialSpeedAnimationDelegate();
animation.RepeatCount = 3;
this.Layer.AddAnimation(animation, "opacity");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
animation.TimingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.FromName (CAMediaTimingFunction.EaseIn);
```